# How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, pattern-matching

Using `awk` or `sed` how can I select lines which are occurring between two different marker patterns? There may be multiple sections marked with these patterns.

For example: 
Suppose the file contains:

```
abc
def1
ghi1
jkl1
mno
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
mno
pqr
stu
```

And the starting pattern is `abc` and ending pattern is `mno`
So, I need the output as:

```
def1
ghi1
jkl1
def2
ghi2
jkl2
```

I am using sed to match the pattern once:

```
sed -e '1,/abc/d' -e '/mno/,$d' <FILE>
```

Is there any way in `sed` or `awk`  to do it repeatedly until the end of file?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Use `awk` with a flag to trigger the print when necessary:

```
$ awk '/abc/{flag=1;next}/mno/{flag=0}flag' file
def1
ghi1
jkl1
def2
ghi2
jkl2
```

How does this work?

- `/abc/` matches lines having this text, as well as `/mno/` does.
- `/abc/{flag=1;next}` sets the `flag` when the text `abc` is found. Then, it skips the line.
- `/mno/{flag=0}` unsets the `flag` when the text `mno` is found.
- The final `flag` is a pattern with the default action, which is to `print $0`: if `flag` is equal 1 the line is printed.

For a more detailed description and examples, together with cases when the patterns are either shown or not, see [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972737/1983854).

Comment: If you want to print everything between and *including* the pattern then you can use  

`awk '/abc/{a=1}/mno/{print;a=0}a' file`.

Comment: Yes, @scai ! or even `awk '/abc/{a=1} a; /mno/{a=0}' file` - with this, putting `a` condition before the `/mno/` we make it evaluate the line as true (and print it) before setting `a=0`. This way we can avoid writing `print`.

Comment: @scai @fedorqui For including pattern output, you can do `awk '/abc/,/mno/' file`

Comment: @scai,@fedorqui : In the above how can we include abc and exclude mno.

Comment: @hkasera `awk '/abc/{flag=1}/mno/{flag=0}flag' file` should make.

Comment: The only drawback of this solution if patterns `abc` and `mno` are the same

Comment: @EirNym that is a weird scenario that can be handled on very different ways: which lines would you like to print? Probably `awk 'flag; /PAT1/{flag=1; next} /PAT1/{flag=0}' file` would make.

Comment: @EirNym Have a look at `seq 100 | awk '/.*1$/{ flag=1-flag }flag'` so see a way of doing it.

Comment: Hi @fedorqui, how to stop after first occurance ?

Comment: @Brain90 probably `/second_pattern/ {exit}` should make.

Comment: Hi @fedorqui  I have a doubt .
If abc  pattern is repeated twice before mno  as follows .
`abc
def1
abc
ghi1
jkl1
mno
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
mno
pqr
stu `  .. 
Here the command will print lines between abc and mno including abc.How to avoid this and get the result for words between abc and mno only.

Comment: @EashwarGadanchi the approach in my answer keeps printing while a true condition is happening. To get what you mention we would have to create some kind of buffering, since it needs to into account things that are not known when you are reading a specific line. See [other approaches to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38972736/1983854) in a related question I created.

Comment: For newbies like me, there is a [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Action-Overview.html).
1. A awk "rule" contains a "pattern" and an "action", either of which (but not both) may be omitted. So `[pattern]  { action }` or `pattern  [{ action }]`.
2. An action consists of one or more awk statements, enclosed in braces (‘{…}’).
—— So the ending `flag` is abbr of `flag {print $0}`

Answer (score 56):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '/^abc$/,/^mno$/{ /^abc$/d; /^mno$/d; p; }'
```

The `-n` option means do not print by default.

The pattern looks for lines containing just `abc` to just `mno`, and then executes the actions in the `{ ... }`.  The first action deletes the `abc` line; the second the `mno` line; and the `p` prints the remaining lines.  You can relax the regexes as required.  Any lines outside the range of `abc`..`mno` are simply not printed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can I know what is the purpose of using `-e`

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya: Mostly it means I like to use it.  Formally, it specifies that the next argument is (part of) the script that `sed` should execute.  If you want or need to use several arguments to include the entire script, then you must use `-e` before each such argument; otherwise, it's optional (but explicit).

Comment: Nice! (I prefer sed over awk.) When using complex regular expressions, it would be nice not to have to repeat them. Isn't it possible to delete the first / last line of the "selected" range? Or to first apply the ``d`` to all lines up to the first match, and then another ``d`` to all lines starting with the second match?

Comment: (Replying to my own comment.) If there's only one section to be cut, I could tentatively solve this e.g. for LaTeX using ``sed -n '1,/\\begin{document}/d;/\\end{document}/d;p'``. (This is cheating a little bit, since the second part does not delete up to the document end, and I would not know how to cut multiple parts as the OP asked for.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what is the reason for inserting the `$` mark, as in `/^abc$`  and others

Comment: The `^` matches the start of a line; the `$` matches the end of line.  Between them, they ensure that only lines containing just `abc` and `mno` are matched.

Answer (score 20):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^abc$/,/^mno$/{//!b};d' file
```

Delete all lines except for those between lines starting `abc` and `mno`

Comment: `!d;//d` golfs 2 characters better :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/31380266/895245

Comment: This is awesome. The `{//!b}` prevents the `abc` and `mno` from being included in the output, but I can't figure out how. Could you explain?

Comment: @Brendan the instruction `//!b` reads if the current line is neither one of the lines that match the range, break and therefore print those lines otherwise all other lines are deleted.

Answer (score 16):

From the previous response's links, the one that did it for me, running `ksh` on Solaris, was this:

```
sed '1,/firstmatch/d;/secondmatch/,$d'
```

- `1,/firstmatch/d`: from line 1 until the first time you find `firstmatch`, delete.
- `/secondmatch/,$d`: from the first occurrance of `secondmatch` until the end of file, delete.
- Semicolon separates the two commands, which are executed in sequence.

Comment: Just curious, why does the range limiter (`1,`) come before `/firstmatch/`? I'm guessing this could also be phrased `'/firstmatch/1,d;/secondmatch,$d'`?

Comment: With "1,/firstmatch/d" you are saying "from line 1 until the first time you find 'firstmatch', delete". Whereas, with "/secondmatch/,$d" you say "from the first occurrance of 'secondmatch' until the end of file, delete". the semicolon separates the two commands, which are executed in sequence.

Answer (score 15):

```
sed '/^abc$/,/^mno$/!d;//d' file
```

golfs two characters better than [ppotong's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17990436/895245) `{//!b};d`

The empty forward slashes `//` mean: "reuse the last regular expression used". and the command does the same as the more understandable:

```
sed '/^abc$/,/^mno$/!d;/^abc$/d;/^mno$/d' file
```

This [seems to be POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

> If an RE is empty (that is, no pattern is specified) sed shall behave as if the last RE used in the last command applied (either as an address or as part of a substitute command) was specified.

Comment: I think the second solution will end up with nothing as the second command is also a range. However kudos for the first.

Comment: @potong true! I have to study more why the first one works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

something like this works for me:

file.awk:

```
BEGIN {
    record=0
}

/^abc$/ {
    record=1
}

/^mno$/ {
    record=0;
    print "s="s;
    s=""
}

!/^abc|mno$/ {
    if (record==1) {
        s = s"\n"$0
    }   
}
```

using: `awk -f file.awk data`...

edit: O_o fedorqui solution is way better/prettier than mine.

Comment: In GNU awk `if (record=1)` should be `if (record==1)`, i.e. double `=`  - see [gawk comparison operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html)

Answer (score 3):

Don_crissti's answer from [Show only text between 2 matching pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17405/16920)?

```
firstmatch="abc"
secondmatch="cdf"
sed "/$firstmatch/,/$secondmatch/!d;//d" infile
```

which is much more efficient than AWK's application, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194662/16920).

Comment: I don't think linking the time comparisons makes much sense here, since the requirements of the questions are quite different, hence the solutions.

Comment: I disagree because we should have some criterias to compare answers. Only a few has SED applications.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lne 'print if((/abc/../mno/) && !(/abc/||/mno/))' your_file
```

Comment: Good to know perl equivalent as it is a pretty good alternative to both awk and sed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use `awk` to print lines between two patterns while **pattern2 also match pattern1**. And the pattern1 line should also be printed.

e.g.
source

```
package AAA
aaa
bbb
ccc
package BBB
ddd
eee
package CCC
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
package DDD
jjj
```

should has an ouput of

```
package BBB
ddd
eee
```

Where pattern1 is `package BBB`, pattern2 is `package \w*`. Note that `CCC` isn't a known value so can't be literally matched.

In this case, neither @scai 's `awk '/abc/{a=1}/mno/{print;a=0}a' file` nor @fedorqui 's `awk '/abc/{a=1} a; /mno/{a=0}' file` works for me.

Finally, I managed to solve it by `awk '/package BBB/{flag=1;print;next}/package \w*/{flag=0}flag' file`, haha

A little more effort result in `awk '/package BBB/{flag=1;print;next}flag;/package \w*/{flag=0}' file`, to print pattern2 line also, that is,

```
package BBB
ddd
eee
package CCC
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with logical operations and increment/decrement operations on a flag:

```
awk '/mno/&&--f||f||/abc/&&f++' file
```

Comment: I'm absolutely certain that i've used awk in the past for this problem, and it was nothing like this complex.

Comment: Obviously the accepted answer in awk that predates my answer by more than 7 years is much more readable, and I saw that answer before I posted mine. I'm just throwing this one here because it is one byte shorter than the accepted answer even after renaming its variable `flag` to `f`, in the spirit of some good ol' code golf fun. :-)