# Is there any way of discarding output until a pattern is matched?

Tags: bash

I'm chaining together multiple commands on the command line. Is there any tool that will allow me to capture output starting with a specific pattern? For example, if I have the following output produced:

```
line 1
line 2 
line 3
line 4
my_pattern
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

Is there some command that will allow me to capture the output starting with my_pattern? This result in the lines

```
my_pattern
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

being captured. The my_pattern line is not mandatory to be included.

Comment: Well this can help: [using sed/awk to select lines between two patterns occurring which is occurring multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17988756/1983854)

Comment: @devnull I did. And you, did you even check the linked question? No need to be rude.

Comment: @fedorqui I'm pretty sure that there would be much better questions that _might help_ in comparison to the linked question.  And asking if you _read the question_ isn't _rude_, or is it?

Comment: @devnull this is one good example I found. Of course there might be better ones, but that one solves this specific problem. It is not rude the sentence itself, but it is what lies beneath.

Comment: @fedorqui Looks like you have a habit of reading way too much.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use `sed` like this:

```
sed -n '/my_pattern/,$p' file
my_pattern
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

That says, don't print anything (`-n`) till you find my_pattern, then print from there to the end of the file. Or in a pipeline:

```
.... | sed -n '/my_pattern/,$p'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk like this for this output redirection:

```
tail -f /logs/apache_error.log | awk '!found && /my_pattern/{found=1} found'
```

This awk will not produce any output until `my_pattern` is found in output and once `my_pattern` appears then all the output text from `tail -f` will be written to stdout (can be redirected to a file as well).

**Testing:**

```
printf "1\n2\n3\n4\nmy_pattern\n5\n6\n7\n" | awk '!found && /my_pattern/ {found=1} found'
my_pattern
5
6
7
```