# awk to exclude range patterns but include the start pattern

Tags: bash, awk, pattern-matching

Say we got an example file:

```
11
12
ss
dd
gg
32
ss
dd
gg
```

So i want to remove the block which meet the pattern ss gg, but i want to keep the start pattern ss

The out put should be

```
11
12
ss
32
ss
```

Using this code

```
awk '/ss/,/gg/{next}1' file
```

It also excludes the start pattern `ss`. How could we keep it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a printing flag like this:

```
$ awk '!flag; /ss/ {flag=1} /gg/ {flag=0}' file
11
12
ss
32
ss
```

This uses a similar logic as [How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17988834/1983854), moving the flag in a way that makes the start pattern to be printed.

- `!flag` since the default value of a variable is `0`, negating it makes it true. This way, we have a default True value, which triggers `awk`s default action: `print $0`.
- `/ss/ {flag=1}` sets the `flag` when the text `ss` is found.
- `/gg/ {flag=0}` unsets the `flag` when the text `gg` is found.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` you can do:

```
sed '/ss/,/gg/{/ss/!d;}' file
11
12
ss
32
ss
```

This `sed` deletes all lines from pattern `ss` to `gg` except when line is `ss` using `!d` command.