# print text between two markers with sed if second marker exists

Tags: awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have a file which contains a list of car manufacturers:

```
$ cat cars
subaru
mercedes
porche
ferrari
audi
mercedes
BMW
ferrari
toyota
lexus
mercedes
VW
$
```

I would like to print all the lines between `mercedes` and `ferrari` so the desired output is:

```
mercedes
porche
ferrari
mercedes
BMW
ferrari
```

My first thought was to use `gsed -n '/mercedes/,/ferrari/p' cars`, but this does obviously not work because `sed` processes file line by line and it has no way to know that last `mercedes` in this file is not followed with `ferrari`. I was able to accomplish this with `gsed -n '/mercedes/h;/^[^mercedes].*$/H;/ferrari/{g;p}' cars`, but I see few problems with this solution:

1) if the end-marker is present, but start-marker is not. For example if last `mercedes` in my file is replaced with `ferrari`, then output is wrong.

2) one can not use regular expressions in `[^mercedes]` part. For example if I would like to use both `mercedes` and `mg-motors` as a start marker, then I can't use `[^m.*s]` regular expression as it would match literal characters `m`, `.`. `*` and `s`.

Is there a smarter way to print text between two markers with `sed` only if the second marker exists? Should one use `awk` in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Your desired output makes no sense.

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines. If you need to use more than s, g, and p (with -n) then you are using the wrong tool as all other sed language constructs became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. Also, never use range expressions as they make the solutions to trivial problems very slightly briefer but then need a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions when the problem becomes even the slightest bit more interesting. It sounds like your problem is with rainy day cases but your sample input/output is only sunny day - reconsider that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'a{a=a"\n"$0}/mercedes/{a=$0}/ferrari/{print a;a=""}' file
mercedes
porche
ferrari
mercedes
BMW
ferrari



sed -n '/mercedes/{:a;N;/ferrari/{p;b};ba}' file
mercedes
porche
ferrari
mercedes
BMW
ferrari
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the file twice:

- first time to count how many `ferrari` you have
- second time to print those lines after a `mercedes` and before a `ferrari` in case there are still some `ferrari` to appear:

That is:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if ($0~/ferrari/) {ferr++}; next}
     /mercedes/{flag=1}
     flag && count<ferr
     /ferrari/{flag=0; count++}' file file
```

Further explanation in [How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17988834/1983854).

#### Test

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{if ($0~/ferrari/) {ferr++}; next} /mercedes/{flag=1} flag && count<ferr; /ferrari/{flag=0; count++}' a a
mercedes
porche
ferrari
mercedes
BMW
ferrari
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/mercedes/!d;:a;/ferrari/p;//d;N;ba' file
```

Use seds grep-like command switch `-n` to print only when requested. Delete all lines other than those that contain `mercedes` then print the pattern space if it contains `ferrari` and delete it. Othewise append the next line and test again.