# How to filter only the lines that are modified in the git context format

Tags: git, git-difftool

I use the following command to identify the no of lines which are been modified in between 2 commits. the b26e..and the e1f5... are the commit hashes

```
git difftool -y -x "diff -c" b26ea5c511970d0211186c3b1e119224465ad365 e2f5104a2dd1afdc27803ead58b74cfd18ae50be
```

below is the output of the file

```
*** /tmp/n90Z9a_Testing.txt 2016-12-02 11:47:59.027168926 +0530
--- /tmp/19ymab_Testing.txt 2016-12-02 11:47:59.027168926 +0530
***************
*** 1,3 ****
  initial commit
  added new line
! added for modification
--- 1,5 ----
  initial commit
  added new line
! added for modification, this is modified.This is modified again
! after modifiying for the second time, this line is added
! This line added for complete deletion and then replace with another
```

from this I need to filter out only the lines that are been modified from the first commit, in simple words I need to filter only this part from the above output

```
*** /tmp/n90Z9a_Testing.txt 2016-12-02 11:47:59.027168926 +0530
--- /tmp/19ymab_Testing.txt 2016-12-02 11:47:59.027168926 +0530
***************
*** 1,3 ****
  initial commit
  added new line
! added for modification
```

How can I filter out it, thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use `git diff <hashcode>` only?

Comment: @Berkay92 then the `unified` output is given which only has the additions and deletions. in the `unified` format we can't identify the actual no of lines that is been modified. for ex: 28 additions and 27 deletions shown in `diff` it could be the result of 1) 28 new additions and 27 deletions 2) 27 modificatins and one new line and etc...

Answer (score 1):

If this is just about [selecting lines between two markers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17989228/6309), you can use `sed`:

```
sed -n -e "/^\*\*\*/,/^---/{ /^---/d; p; }"
```

That is:

```
git difftool -y -x "diff -c" <shaX> <shaY> | sed -n -e "/^\*\*\*/,/^---/{ /^---/d; p; }"
```

That will print everything between '`***`' (included) and '`---`' (excluded)

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
git difftool -y -x "diff -c" <commitHash1> <commithash2> | awk '/\*\*\*/{flag=1}/---/{print;flag=0}flag'
```

To see more examples of selecting lines between 2 marker patterns with `awk` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns/38972737#38972737)

Comment: Please do not post bare code answers, also provide some commentary on what your code is doing.