# Extract range using regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

For example

```
1cn1
1cn2
1cn3
1cn4
1cn5
1cn6
1cn7
1cn8
1cn9
1cn10
1cn11
1cn12
```

extract lines between `1cn8` to `1cn12`

like this i have hundreds of line, want to extract any range by giving the input.

```
$ cat test | grep '[$0-9]'
1cn1
1cn2
1cn3
1cn4
1cn5
1cn6
1cn7
1cn8
1cn9
1cn10
1cn11
1cn12
```

these are node names, want to extract node names within the node range. lines starting from`1cn8` till `1cn12`

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck at? What is the expected output

Comment: cat test
1cn1
1cn2
1cn3
1cn4
1cn5
1cn6
1cn7
1cn8
1cn9
1cn10
1cn11
1cn12

Comment: Please update the question and add what you have tried. The question is unclear as *between `1cn8` to `1cn12`* do you mean lines starting from `1cn8` till `1cn12` or any line which is between `8-12` in the stirng?

Comment: cat test | grep '[$0-9]'
1cn1
1cn2
1cn3
1cn4
1cn5
1cn6
1cn7
1cn8
1cn9
1cn10
1cn11
1cn12

Comment: lines starting from 1cn8 till 1cn12

Comment: This will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/17988834/3150943

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
[[:alnum:]]{3}([8-9]|1[0-2])
```

Short explanation:

- `[[:alnum:]]{3}`: matchs with any letter (upper or lower case) and digits, over 3 times;
- `([8-9]|1[0-2])`: matchs with 8 and 9 `[8-9]` OR `|`, the number one with 0, 1 or 2, `1[0-2]`

```
$ cat test
1cn1
1cn2
1cn3
1cn4
1cn5
1cn6
1cn7
1cn8
1cn9
1cn10
1cn11
1cn12
$ egrep '[[:alnum:]]{3}([8-9]|1[0-2])' test
1cn8
1cn9
1cn10
1cn11
1cn12
```