# How to select two specific lines with awk?

Tags: bash, awk

/!\ The question is basically solved, see my own answer below for more details and a subsidiary question /!\

I'm trying to add two lines based on specific word, but all I could find is adding everything after some pattern: [How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w)

Which is not what I'm looking after.

Consider the following output:

```
aji 1
bsk 2
cmq 3
doh 4
enr 5
fwp 6
gzx 7
```

What I'm trying to get is something like cmq + fwp, which output should be:

```
9
```

I do know how to add values, but I'm missing the `select line containing cmq, then select line containing fwp` part.

So, is there a way awk could strictly select two specific lines independently (then add them) ?

Edit:

As far as I know, matching words is `awk '/cmq/'`, but I need to do that for let's say "fwp" too so I can add them.

Comment: save the value in variable for first match and add it when the second match is found....

Comment: Is there a way to not use variables ? I'll always have two values. I do however know how to add values, but I'm missing the "select line containing c, then select line containing f" part.

Comment: @X.LINK, could be there repeated lines (with same letter)?

Comment: As far as I know, there won't be repeating lines.

Comment: @X.LINK not sure what you mean by that... if you want a way to select two different lines, use alternation or other regex features.. for example, `/cmq|fwp/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^(cmq|fwp)$/{sum+=$2} END { print sum}'  infile
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk '$1 ~ /^(cmq|fwp)$/{     # look for the match in first field
       sum+=$2               # sum up 2nd field ($2) value,where sum is variable
     }
     END{                    # at the end
       print sum             # print variable sum
     }' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
aji 1
bsk 2
cmq 3
doh 4
enr 5
fwp 6
gzx 7

$ awk '$1 ~ /^(cmq|fwp)$/{sum+=$2} END { print sum}'  infile
9
```

Comment: Is there a way to strictly and independently search for c then f ? "c" may be "hju" or "kwg" (may not start with "c") and "f" may be "nyo" or "ltm" (may not start with "f"). All I could find for matching word is " awk '/kwg/' ", but I need to do that for let's say "nyo" too so I can add them.

Comment: @X.LINK you can do like this also `awk '$1=="c"{ c = $2 } $2 == "f" {f = $2}END{ print c +  f }' infile`

Comment: You can search for the entire phrases with `awk '/cmq|fwp/ { s += $2 } END { print s}' file` and if you need more, just add more like `/cmq|fwp|nyo|itm/` etc. If you want to restrict to the first field and require the match to be equal to the first field, that would be `awk '$1 ~ /^(cmq|fwp)$/ { ...`

Comment: @triplee : That's what I was searching for, thanks ! So now the almost correct way is: ` awk '/cmq|fwp/ {sum+=$2} END { print sum}' `. The only problem is that sum is still a variable. But I'm afraid there's no way to skip that.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for comment, I hope X.Link is happy now.

Comment: @AkshayHegde: Pretty much, both of you guys answered correctly. Please edit your answer with: " awk '/cmq|fwp/ {sum+=$2} END { print sum}'  " so I can mark it as a valid answer. By the way, how do you underline code in comments ? I used ` `, but it didn't worked.

Comment: @X.LINK modified post, don't use quotes to just use grave accents

Comment: `print sum+0` to get numeric output even when neither string exists in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Now, for a more generic way this time -which even works for subtracting-:

```
awk '/cmq/{x=$2} /fwp/{y=$2} END {print x+y}'
```

Where:

```
awk '          # Invoking awk and its instructions
/cmq/{x=$2}    # Select line with "cmq", then set its value to x. Both must be tied
/fwp/{y=$2}    # Select line with "fwp", then set its value to y. Both must be tied
END            # Ends pattern matching/creation
{print x+y}    # Print the calculated result
'              # Ending awk's instructions
```

Unfortuanately, two variables are used (x and y).

So, I'm still interested on finding how to do it without any variable, or only one at the very most.

I do have a single-variable way for summing:

```
awk '/cmq|fwp/ {x+=$2} END {print x}'
```

But doing this for subtracting:

```
awk '/cmq|fwp/ {x-=$2} END {print x}'
```

doesn't work.

As an subsidiary question, anyone knows to achieve such subtracting without or with only one variable ?

Comment: probably this : `x=x!=""?x-$2:$2` , will give `-3`, please don't edit again and again on same question, it will be difficult for readers to understand.

Comment: It worked ! However, despite understanding the ternary part, what does ` !="" ` means ?

Comment: `x!=""` meas  if `x` is not equal to null

Comment: @AkshayHegde Avoid using negatives so you avoid double-negatives creeping in. `x=(x!=""?x-$2:$2)` can be written without a negative as `x=(x==""?$2:x-$2)`. Its also a good idea to always parenthesize your ternary expressions for readability and to avoid syntax errors in some contexts in some awks.

Comment: @EdMorton sure, I will note your words, X.link please parenthesize your ternary expressions as Ed suggested above.