# Extract set of lines using delimiters in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to extract set of lines between specific patterns in bash.
My input file:

```
=========
a
b
ven
c
d
=========
abc
def
venkata
sad
dada
=========
```

I am trying to extract only the lines between two `=======` which contains the pattern `venkata` in between. ie., the second section in the above eg (abc ... dada).
 I have tried `sed`, but it does not give what I need exactly.

I tried splitting this task to getting lines above `venkata` and the lines below it separately.

Using `sed -n -e '/=====/,/venkata/p'` gives starting from the beginning of the input, which is not what I need.
Any thoughts ?

**Edit:**  The number of lines between `=======` can be of any number and `venkata` can be at any line, not necessarily the exact middle. 
There can be multiple words,numbers,symbols in each line. This is just a sample

**Edit 2:** [How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w) accepted answer is close, but gives the output from the first match. That is not what I am looking for.
Based on the command in the answer of that question, it would set the flag when the first `====` is found.
I need the `====` just before `venkata`, which need not be the very first match.
**That answer does not help me solve my problem**

Comment: could be there lines with more than one word?

Comment: Yes there could be more than one word. And also its not limited to alphabets, each line can have alphabets, numbers, special characters or mix of all these.

Comment: @VenkataKrishna: Did you check `awk` solution I posted below?

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu-awk` you can do this:

```
awk -v RS='={2,}\n' -v ORS= '/venkata/' file

abc
def
venkata
sad
dada
```

If you don't have `gnu-awk` then use:

```
awk '/={2,}/{if (s && data ~ /venkata/) printf "%s", data; s=1; data=""; next} s{data = data $0 RS}' file
```

Comment: If you don't have `gnu-awk` then use: `awk '/={2,}/{if (s && data ~ /venkata/) printf "%s", data; s=1; data=""; next} s{data = data $0 RS}' file`

Comment: I dont have gnu-awk, I tried the respective solution. But it didn't work out. It didn't return anything back. I wasn't clear with the logic to try and debug the solution given.

Comment: [Check this working demo with suggested alternate `awk` command](https://ideone.com/sYMyca) If you have different sample data then edit the question and I will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` you can accomplish the same:

```
cat infile | grep -A 2 -B 2 "venkata"
```

The options `-A` and `-B` print a number of trailing and leading lines respectively.

As pointed out by @Jan Gassen, if you want the same amount of lines unde and above the matching pattern, you can make it even simpler by:

```
cat infile | grep -C 2 "venkata"
```

Comment: or simpler: `grep -C 2 "venkata" file`