# How to select data between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with sed?

Tags: sed

How to select data between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with sed?

I've read some related threads here including this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w), but I'm still confused with sed's complicated parameters.

My data are some web page source codes, they are total mess and not broken in lines.

For example:

```html
123<div>abc</div><span>DEF</span><div>ghi</div>456
```

I need to get an output as follow, from the first `<div>` to the last `</div>`, how can I do it with sed?:

```html
<div>abc</div><span>DEF</span><div>ghi</div>
```

Second question: with the result above, how to get the data `<span>DEF</span>`?

Many thanks:)

Comment: While it is OK to use regex for very simple tasks, your solution needs a proper HTML parser and some program / script.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular example you provided, this is the regex:

```
<div>.*<\/div>
```

Test it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/lm02rE/1).