# Selecting lines between marker patterns where one pattern may occur twice

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

If I have a file that contains some text data such as

```
PATTERN1
TEXT1
PATTERN1
TEXT2
PATTERN2
```

How would I select the TEXT2 data from this file I know PATTERN1 and PATTERN2 ?
I have tried using awk as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w), but it prints both TEXT1 and TEXT2.

Answer (score 2):

If TEXT2 is always surrounded by PATTERN1 and PATTERN2 you can use grep:

```
grep -B2 "PATTERN2" file | grep -A1 "PATTERN1" | grep -v "PATTERN1"
```

- `grep -B2 "PATTERN2"` -> grab PATTERN2 and the preceding 2 lines
- `grep -A1 "PATTERN1"` -> from these three lines, grab PATTERN1 and the line after
- `grep -v "PATTERN1"` -> get rid of the line/s containing PATTERN1 and you are left with TEXT2

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '
inBlock {
    if ( /PATTERN2/ ) {
        printf "%s", block
        inBlock = 0
    } else {
        block = block $0 ORS
    }
}
/PATTERN1/ {
    inBlock = 1
    block = ""
}
' file
TEXT2
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/PATTERN1/{z;x;d};/PATTERN2/!{H;d};g;s/.//p;d' file
```

If the current line contains `PATTERN1`, clear the line and delete the hold space (HS).

If the current line does not contain `PATTERN2`, append it to the HS and delete the line.

If the current line contains `PATTERN2`, replace it by the contents of the HS, remove the first character (which will be an introduced newline), print the result and delete the line.

Alternative:

```
sed -En '/PATTERN1/{:a;/PATTERN1/z;N;/PATTERN2/!ba;s/.(.*)\n.*/\1/p}' file
```

The first solution presupposes that the file will contain `PATTERN1` and `PATTERN2`, the second does not.

Answer (score 1):

If `PATTERN2` can occure multiple times, this extracts only inner text:

```
sed '/PATTERN1/h;//!H;/PATTERN2/!d;//{x;/PATTERN1/!d}'
```

If `PATTERN2` can occur only once, you can use such sed script:

```
sed -n '/PATTERN1/h;//!H;/PATTERN2/{x;p}' input_file.txt
```

or:

```
sed '/PATTERN1/h;//!H;/PATTERN2/!d;//x'
```

You can reverse the lines, then use `sed` with 2 addresses and reverse lines again:

```
tac input_file.txt | sed -n '/PATTERN2/,/PATTERN1/p' | tac
```

With `sed -z` we could remove everything in front and after the patterns, since regex is greedy:

```
sed -z 's/.*\(PATTERN1\n\)/\1/;s/\(PATTERN2\n\).*/\1/g'
```

Comment: If I run the first solution against the example, the result contains both `PATTERN1` and `PATTERN2`, I was under the impression that the OP wanted these removed.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne 'print(@buffer), $inside = @buffer = () if /PATTERN2/;
          push @buffer, $_ if $inside;
          @buffer = (), $inside = 1 if /PATTERN1/;
' -- file.txt
```

We keep an array of lines to output in @buffer. We also keep a flag $inside that's set to true if we've met PATTERN1, but not PATTERN2 yet.

- If we see PATTERN2, we print the buffer and clear the flag.
- If we are inside, we remember the current line.
- If we see PATTERN1, regardless of whether we've seen it before or not, we clear the buffer and set the flag.