# Searching and replacing values recursively in the same time

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, jinja2

I have a folder of Ansible playbooks, in which I want to grep specific YAML block and replace one of the Jinja2 variables with its value from the playbook folder.

**For example:**

```
grep -R -A 35 -w -h 'test_profiles:' .

test_profiles:
  - name: test_1
  source: '{{ service_name }}'
```

So I want to interpolate the `service_name` variable with its value

What I tried is to grep for the `service_name` but couldn't find a way to recursively replace the variable with its respective search result for each playbook folder

**Folder structure:**

- playbook 1

  - main.yml < contains `service_name` value
  - tasks

    - file.yml < contains `test_profiles` block which I need to replace the `service_name` within it
- playbook 2

  - main.yml
  - tasks

    - file.yml
- ... etc

main.yml from playbook 1 sample:

```
---
service_name: 'service 1'
```

main.yml from playbook 2 sample:

```
---
service_name: 'service 2'
```

file.yml from playbook 1 sample:

```
---
test_profiles:
  - name: test_1
  source: '{{ service_name }}'

other_header:
   key: value
```

file.yml from playbook 2 sample:

```
---
test_profiles:
  - name: test_2
  source: '{{ service_name }}'

another_header:
   another_key: value
```

**Expected result:**

```
test_profiles:
  - name: test_1
  source: 'service 1'
test_profiles:
  - name: test_2
  source: 'service 2'
test_profiles:
  - name: test_3
  source: 'service 3'
```

grep command I tried to get the `service_name` variable:

```
grep -R -oE 'service_name=([a-zA-Z]*-*[a-zA-Z]*)*|service_name:(\s*[a-zA-Z]*-*[a-zA-Z]*)*' .
```

But I couldn't find a way to combine both commands, to result in the expected result above.

Comment: While I'm sure some clever `awk` person will give you something here, quite frankly I'd probably write a small python script :D

Comment: I will try writing it now, was thinking the same as well, thanks @urbanespaceman

Comment: Please update your question so that you have 2 rows of sample file main.yml and 2 blocks of file.yml and the exact result for them.

Comment: Do you want to edit the file.yml files in place, or you need the output only as you indicated in the expected result?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Yes I need the output only

Comment: Are there more lines into `file.yml` that you don't want? And want to keep only the `test_profiles` block, which ends with an empty line?

Comment: Yes exactly only `test_profiles` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution runs one `awk` per playbook. Parse the `main.yml` and store the value of `service_name`. Parse the second file and print only the lines block (starting with `test_profiles:` and ending with a line empty or with only white-space characters) with the variable replaced. You execute the script below from the root of your directory structure.

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in playbook*; do
    [[ -f "$d"/main.yml ]] && [[ -f "$d"/tasks/file.yml ]] || continue
    awk -F"'" 'FNR==NR && /^service_name:/{s=$2;next} {FS=OFS}
           /test_profiles:/ {f=1}
           f {gsub("{{ service_name }}",s)}
           f && (NF==0) {f=0}
           f' "$d"/main.yml "$d"/tasks/file.yml
done
```

Also if there is no value in the `main.yml`, this prints empty string for `{{ service_name }}`, if this is not a feature but a bug, we can change it. And any playbook not having both files at place, is being ignored.

---

Reference:

[How to read two files with awk (`NR==FNR`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-are-nr-and-fnr-and-what-does-nr-fnr-imply)

[gsub and the other `GNU awk` string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

[How to print using a flag a block between start and end pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w)