# How to get values with yml file with bash?

Tags: bash, yaml

I have this yml file, How do i retrieve only the values under backends with bash? I know there's sed, grep and awk. I do not know what the best way to retrieve the data

```
affinityCookieTtlSec: 0
backends:
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 0.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 1.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
connectionDraining:
  drainingTimeoutSec: 300
creationTimestamp: '2021-09-08'
description: ''
enableCDN: false
healthChecks:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
kind: compute#backendService
loadBalancingScheme: EXTERNAL
logConfig:
  enable: false
name: backend
port: 80
portName: portname
protocol: HTTP
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
sessionAffinity: NONE
timeoutSec: 30
```

Expected output

```
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 0.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 1.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
```

Comment: Use `awk`. When the line matches `/backends:/`, start reading and printing lines until you get another line that begins with a letter. Then exit.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w using those answers: `awk '/^backends:/{flag=1;next}/^[^- ]/{flag=0}flag' file`

Comment: Or maybe `grep`:    `grep -A 8 '^backends:' your.yml | grep '^-\|^ '` or  maybe  `grep -A 8 '^backends:' your.yml | tail -n 8`  (Although, the `awk` option suggested by @JerryJeremiah would be my preference)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply with `awk` by setting a flag `f` true when you want to output the line and then test when beginning characters are no longer `' '` or `'-'` and quit printing at that point, e.g.

```bash
awk '/^backends:/{f=1; next} f {if ($0 ~/^[ -]/) print; else f=0}' file.yml
```

Instead of setting `f=0` you can simply call `exit` at that point -- but be aware, if you have an `END` rule, it will be run after `exit` is called. (there is no `END` rule here)

A shorter rearrangement could be:

```bash
awk '/^backends:/{f=1; next} /^[^ -]/{f=0} f' file.yml
```

(a bit less readable -- up to you)

Note above, a condition alone, e.g. `f` (shorthand for `f != 0`), will invoke the default action of `print`. So if `f != 0`, simply providing `f` as a standalone condition will cause the records (lines) to print while that condition is true without also including the `{ print }` after it.

**Example Output**

```
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 0.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 1.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use yq? It's a lightweight and portable command-line YAML, JSON and XML processor, see https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

```bash
echo "affinityCookieTtlSec: 0
backends:
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 0.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 1.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
connectionDraining:
  drainingTimeoutSec: 300
creationTimestamp: '2021-09-08'
description: ''
enableCDN: false
healthChecks:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
kind: compute#backendService
loadBalancingScheme: EXTERNAL
logConfig:
  enable: false
name: backend
port: 80
portName: portname
protocol: HTTP
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
sessionAffinity: NONE
timeoutSec: 30" | yq .backends
```

Which prints:

```yaml
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 0.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 1.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
```

Comment: Definitely a nice utility Only downside personally is go, but other than that it looks like a good yaml aware parser.