# awk extract lines between two patterns with a twist

Tags: awk

I have a type of data file that contains only once (!) the following block of text:

```
Begin final coordinates
     new unit-cell volume =    460.57251 a.u.^3 (    68.24980 Ang^3 )
     density =      7.37364 g/cm^3

CELL_PARAMETERS (alat=  7.29434300)
   0.995319813   0.000000000   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.995319813   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.000000000   1.197882354

ATOMIC_POSITIONS (crystal)
Pb            0.0000000000        0.0000000000       -0.0166356359
O             0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.1549702780
Ti            0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.5327649171
O             0.0000000000        0.5000000000        0.6381882204
O             0.5000000000        0.0000000000        0.6381882204
End final coordinates
```

I have found how to extract the entire block of lines between the `Begin final coordinates` and `End final coordinates` patterns but I need to it to be more refined. I would like to extract first the three lines below the line starting with `CELL_PARAMETERS`. Then I would like to extract (with another action not in the same awk command), the 5 lines below ATOMIC_POSITIONS.

I have to make an observation here: I said at the beginning the the block of text appears only once and this is true for that specific form with `Begin final coordinates` and `End final coordinates`. Throughout the data file there are many blocks with this form:

```
CELL_PARAMETERS (alat=  7.29434300)
   0.995319813   0.000000000   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.995319813   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.000000000   1.197882354

ATOMIC_POSITIONS (crystal)
Pb            0.0000000000        0.0000000000       -0.0166356359
O             0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.1549702780
Ti            0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.5327649171
O             0.0000000000        0.5000000000        0.6381882204
O             0.5000000000        0.0000000000        0.6381882204
```

So unfortunately I cannot just use the `CELL_PARAMETERS` and `ATOMIC_POSITIONS` lines as patterns. The only ones appearing only once are the `Begin final coordinates` and `End final coordinates` so I have to extract text relative to these lines.

I have tried to marry the method to extract lines between two patterns from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17988756/4873946) with the one for skipping N lines after finding pattern from [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1312796/72409). Unfortunately I can't make it work.

So my idea was:

1. for the first case: I was trying to find the `Begin final coordinates` pattern and skip 5 lines including the one with the pattern) then print the 3 lines I am interested in and then skip the rest until the `End final coordinates`.
2. for the second case: find `Begin final coordinates` then skip the lines until ATOMIC_POSITIONS (skipping this one too), print the next 5 lines until the `End final coordinates`.

Can this be done?

Update:

I have just tried this:

```
awk '/Begin final coordinates/ {n=NR+9} n < NR < n+3'
```

but i get syntax error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: /Begin final coordinates/ {n=NR+9} n<NR<n+3
awk: cmd. line:1:                                        ^ syntax error
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Update2:

Hold the presses, I got it!

1. this solves the first case: `awk '/Begin final coordinates/{n=NR+4;m=NR+8} (n<NR) && (NR<m)' file`
2. this solves the second case: `awk '/Begin final coordinates/{n=NR+9;m=NR+8} (n<NR) && (NR<m)' file`

Is not very nice but it will do the job!

Answer (score 3):

Hold the presses, I got it!

1. this solves the first case:

   ```bash
   awk '/Begin final coordinates/{n=NR+4;m=NR+8} (n<NR) && (NR<m)' file
   ```
2. this solves the second case:

   ```bash
   awk '/Begin final coordinates/{n=NR+9;m=NR+8} (n<NR) && (NR<m)' file
   ```

Answer (score 1):

With this you only need to read the input once:

```
awk '/Begin final coordinates/{n1=NR+4;m1=NR+8; n2=NR+9;m2=NR+8} 
     (n1<NR) && (NR<m1){ print > "CELL_PARAMETERS.txt"; }
     (n2<NR) && (NR<m2){ print > "ATOMIC_POSITIONS.txt"; }
     ' file
```

Comment: ooo I like this! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Begin final` block only occurs after all of the other blocks:

```
$ awk '/^Begin final/{f=1} c&&c--; f && /^CELL/{c=3}' file
   0.995319813   0.000000000   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.995319813   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.000000000   1.197882354

$ awk '/^Begin final/{f=1} c&&c--; f && /^ATOMIC/{c=5}' file
Pb            0.0000000000        0.0000000000       -0.0166356359
O             0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.1549702780
Ti            0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.5327649171
O             0.0000000000        0.5000000000        0.6381882204
O             0.5000000000        0.0000000000        0.6381882204
```

or if it could appear anywhere then change `c&&c--;` to `c{print; if (!c--) exit}`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for related idioms.